# FOR XML PATH - dynamic node?

Tags: sql, xml

I have this sample table.

rate_id|account_id|definition|category|pmpm_override|amount

1|a1|PSPM|c1|null|100

2|a1|PSPM|c2|null|200

3|a1|PC|c3|null|150

4|a1|PC|c4|null|250

5|a2|PMPM|c5|TRUE|400

6|a2|PMPM|c3|TRUE|500

7|a3|PMPM|c2|FALSE|600

The problem focuses on the 'definition' column as its value determines the node name that elements category, amount, and pmpm_override are under.

e.g., When definition=PSPM the node is pspmrate, when definition=PC node is pcrate, etc.

Using the FOR XML PATH I am looking to return the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Rates>
    <rate_id id="1">
    <account_id>a1</account_id>
    <pspmrate>
        <category>c1</category>
        <amount>100</amount>
    </pspmrate>
    </rate_id>
    <rate_id id="2">
    <account_id>a1</account_id>
    <pspmrate>
        <category>c2</category>
        <amount>200</amount>
    </pspmrate>
    </rate_id>
    <rate_id id="3">
    <account_id>a1</account_id>
    <pcrate>
        <category>c3</category>
        <amount>150</amount>        
    </pcrate>
    </rate_id>
    <rate_id id="4">
    <account_id>a1</account_id>
    <pcrate>
        <category>c4</category>
        <amount>250</amount>        
    </pcrate>
    </rate_id>
    <rate_id id="5">
    <account_id>a2</account_id>
    <pmpmrate>
        <category>c5</category>
        <amount>400</amount>        
        <pmpm_override>true</pmpm_override>
    </pmpmrate>
    </rate_id>
    <rate_id id="6">
    <account_id>a2</account_id>
    <pmpmrate>
        <category>c3</category>
        <amount>500</amount>        
        <pmpm_override>true</pmpm_override>
    </pmpmrate>
    </rate_id>
    <rate_id id="7">
    <account_id>a3</account_id>
    <pmpmrate>
        <category>c2</category>
        <amount>600</amount>        
        <pmpm_override>false</pmpm_override>
    </pmpmrate>
    </rate_id>
</Rates>
```

For now I have a query that returns the correct structure minus the node name (I have hard coded this with FOR XML PATH('pspmrate')) and so the rate ids 3-7 have the wrong node.

In reality the query code is much much larger and structure is a bit more complex but this sample is representative of what I'm looking for - I imagine there is way to do perform this with dynamic sql but I'm trying to avoid working and troubleshooting a huge query string if possible.

I guess I'm looking for a way to dynamically determine the XML PATH.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with a case expression if you have a known number of definitions:

```
SELECT  [@id] = rate_id,
        account_id,
        CASE definition
            WHEN 'PC' THEN (SELECT pmpm_override, amount, category FOR XML PATH('pcrate'), TYPE)
            WHEN 'PMPM' THEN (SELECT pmpm_override, amount, category FOR XML PATH('pmpmrate'), TYPE) 
            WHEN 'PSPM' THEN (SELECT pmpm_override, amount, category FOR XML PATH('pspmrate'), TYPE)
        END
FROM    T
FOR XML PATH('rate_id'), ROOT('rates');
```

If not then you will need dynamic sql to build your case expression:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT  @SQL = 'SELECT  [@id] = rate_id,
                        account_id,
                        CASE definition
                            ' + (SELECT 'WHEN ''' + Definition + 
                                        ''' THEN (SELECT pmpm_override, amount, category FOR XML PATH(''' + 
                                        LOWER(Definition) + 'rate''), TYPE) '
                                FROM    T
                                GROUP BY Definition
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') + '
                        END
                FROM    T
                FOR XML PATH(''rate_id''), ROOT(''rates'');';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: GarethD thanks for your feedback.  There are indeed a finite number of 'definition' values (5).  I thought some type of case statement may be the way to go and I will try your first suggestion.  I guess my reservation of this is that within each of the WHEN statements there in fact many subqueries (not included in the sample) for other structured elements that ARE the same within each 'definition' node. Those will just make my query HUGE!  I'll give it a try!! THANKS!

Comment: If you are repeating the same sub query multiple times then you may be able to simplify things by encapsulating the logic in a common table expression, and reusing that